# Can't get value in dll function when pass string from inno to dll?

Tags: dll, inno-setup, param

I want to pass a string to my dll funcfion, but the function cannot get the value.
first I get the string from cmd line using GetMyParam function. it's right.then, i pass
the value to my dll using innotest function.

```
function innotest(PName:string):Integer;
external 'innotest@E:\client\branch\maintain\1.4\bin\sdostate-debug\update.dll stdcall setuponly';

function GetMyParam(PName:string):string;
var
  CmdLine : String;
  CmdLineLen : Integer;
  i : Integer;
begin
    Result := '';
    CmdLineLen:=ParamCount();
    for i:=0 to CmdLineLen do
    begin
    CmdLine:=ParamStr(i);
    if CmdLine = PName then
      begin
          CmdLine:=ParamStr(i+1);
          Result := CmdLine;
          Exit;
      end;
    end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep); 
var 
res: String;

begin
if (CurStep = ssPostInstall) and (Pos('setup', WizardSelectedTasks(false)) > 0)then
begin
res := GetMyParam('-myParam');
MsgBox(res, mbInformation, mb_Ok);
innotest(res);
end;
end;
```

Msgbox has the res value.
here is my dll code: the string's length is 1.

```
DWORD Update::innotest(string str)
{
    LPCWSTR s = StringHelper::ANSIToUnicode(str).c_str();
    MessageBox(0,s,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What version of InnoSetup are you using and ANSI or Unicode ? If ANSI then this won't be possible. You'd have to use Unicode version of InnoSetup since you're using LPCWSTR Unicode string in your library and when you have ANSI version of InnoSetup, string is there mapped to ANSI string and there's no type for Unicode string.

Comment: i have implemented the StringHelper for converting the Ansi string to Unicode. this way doesn't work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Your function has ANSI string as a parameter (`str` is ANSI string) and you have Unicode InnoSetup, right ? If so, then in InnoSetup function import change your parameter to `PName: AnsiString` and you'll be fine.

Comment: I checked my InnoSetup is Non Unicode.Then I downloaded Unicode InnoSetup and change (string str) to (wstring str) in my dll module. and MessageBox return Garbled and a Runtime Error Access violation in my dll module, could you give me some help? thanks!!

Comment: Now I see it, the `string` data type is not a pointer to string, right ? You have to use pointer to string type for passing string parameters between InnoSetup and your library. So you can simply use `LPCWSTR` for your library parameter and when you have Unicode InnoSetup, you can keep your import as it is.

Comment: yeah . I have solved the problem as your suggestion. Thanks for your kindness and patience！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `string` type in your function parameter, what is a sequence of characters in memory, that InnoSetup cannot reach directly. You have to use pointer to string type to get it to work. So when you are using Unicode InnoSetup, change your library function parameter to have an Unicode string pointer type the following way. Then you can keep your InnoSetup script as it is:

```
DWORD Update::innotest(LPCWSTR str)
{
    MessageBox(0,s,0,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, using `string` as a parameter is probably `std::string`, which is much more than a simple sequence of characters and completely incompatible as a mixed-language-DLL function parameter.  (And as a side note, you should never try to pass `string` by value anyway, even within your own library.)